# combining multiple table with different number of columns based on one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, android-room

I am performing two SELECT queries. First is to get the `roomid, roomname, message, sender, date` and the second is to get the number of new joined user into the room as you can see the result in the `?column?`. I get that table by using `UNION` on both of the results. But this version is not desired, it should be unique on the `roomid` column. I have been trying to figure this out for days. Please point me to the right direction.

Followings are my SQL queries:

```
select roomdetails.roomid as roomid, roomname, message, sender, date, 0 
from roomdetails
union
select convo.roomid as roomid, null, null, null, null, count(convo.id) 
from convo 
group by convo.roomid
```

How to make it so that the value of `roomid` contains no duplicate like below?

[image]

Comment: Postgres or SQLite? Those are two very different database products

Comment: i am testing this on my postgresql.. but later on i will try on sqlite too. Does my query will produce different output on different engine?

Comment: Don't test and develop on a DBMS that you won't use in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correlated subquery looks like a direct *( without using redundant nulls )* option to be considered :

```
select roomid, roomname, message, sender, date, 
       ( select count(c.id) from convo c where c.roomid = r.roomid ) as cnt_roomid
  from roomdetails r
```

Comment: very nice :) @dude

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 select roomdetails.roomid as roomid, roomname, message, sender, date,mysum
  from roomdetails join (
       select convo.roomid as roomid,count(convo.id) mysum 
        from convo group by convo.roomid
    ) a using (roomid)
```

Comment: I have tried this and I think we are nearly there boys... error im getting now is "common column name 'roomid' appears more than once in left table"